# Issue filling up and outputting a 3D array

Tags: c++, random, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 3-Dimensional array which gets filled up with pseudo-random numbers ranging from 0 to 9 (inclusive). This is my first time working with arrays containing more than 2 dimensions, so I am a bit lost.

At first the only number being inputted into the array was a 1, but after changing some code around, every number but the last one is a 1, and the last digit is pseudo-random. To make matters worse with the new situation I am in, when I hit enter, I get a weird error message.[image: weird error message]

Besides these two errors (error filling up array, and debug error), I also cannot figure out how in the world to print it out in 3 groups of 3 x 3 numbers, although right now, that is a lower issue on my agenda (although hints for that would be appreciated).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));


    const int arrayRow = 3, arrayColumns = 3, arrayDepth = 3;

    int fun[arrayRow][arrayColumns][arrayDepth];

    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++){
            for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++){
                int value = rand() % 10;
                fun[r][c][d] = value;
                cout << fun[arrayRow][arrayColumns][arrayDepth];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Complete." << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a 3x3x3 array.

Then you proceed to initialize as if it was a 4x4x4 array. Here's a simplified explanation of where your code goes wrong:

```
int foo[3];
```

This declares a 3-element array. `foo[0]` through `foo[2]`.

```
for (int bar=0; bar<4; ++bar)
{
    foo[bar]=1;
}
```

This attempts to initialize `foo[0]` through `foo[3]`. Four elements. Three-element array.

Undefined behavior.

Your code makes the same error, but with a 3-dimensional array, in all three dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun[arrayRow][arrayColumns][arrayDepth]
```

allocates an array that can be indexed with a range of 0 .. 2 on each axis.

```
 for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++){
```

roams from 0 to 3 and overruns the array.

```
for (int r = 0; r < arrayRow; r++){
```

will solve that. You will have to do the same for the other `for` loops as well as they are all out of range.

In addition,

```
cout << fun[arrayRow][arrayColumns][arrayDepth];
```

resolves to

```
cout << fun[3][3][3];
```

and is out of range and always returns the same value.